# How to make Python to run 4 nested loops faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, loops, nested-loops

I have 4 nested loops in my Python code and it takes ages to finish all the loops when the grids are big. For example, here is a piece of my code:

```
from itertools import product

T        =  50
beta     =  0.98 
alpha    =  0.3
delta    =  0.1

xss      =  ((1 / beta - (1 - delta)) / alpha)**(1 / (alpha - 1))
yss      =  xss**alpha

x        =  np.linspace(0.8 * xss, 1.4 * xss, T,dtype='float32')
y        =  np.linspace(yss, 1.2 * yss, T,dtype='float32')

for i,j,a,b in product(range(T),range(T),range(T),range(T)):
    z[i*T+a,j*T+b]    =  x[i]**alpha + (1 - delta) * x[i] + y[j] - x[a] - y[b]
```

Is there any solution to help Python create matrix `z` faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to separate the `b` loop from the other three. That allows you to precompute things that don't depend on `b`, like `x[i]**alpha + (1 - delta) * x[i] + y[j] - x[a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping in Python is slow. As much as possible, try to keep it inside `numpy`. A good start should be to notice that you are creating a new matrix based on four parameters; convert the parameters to a 4-dimensional array, and let the `numpy` broadcasting take care of the looping for you. This one command should be all you need, and it will be very, very fast:

```
z4 = (
    (x ** alpha + (1 - delta) * x)[:, None, None, None]
    + y[None, None, :, None]
    - x[None, :, None, None]
    - y[None, None, None, :]
)
```

You may notice that everything that has to do with `i` index in your code has been placed here in the first dimension (by `[:, None, None, None]`); everything to do with `j` in the third (by `[None, None, :, None]`), etc. This will end up with shape `[T, T, T, T]`, one dimension for each of the parameters (`i`, `a`, `j` and `b` in your code, respectively). After that, because the dimensions are ordered appropriately, you can collapse it to `[T * T, T * T]` shape by

```
z = np.reshape(z4, [T * T, T * T])
```

There is a slight difference in the results because my calculation stays entirely in `float32` land, while yours wanders into `float64` then gets forced into whatever `z.dtype` is (I can't see the definition of `z` in your code). This happens because `x ** alpha` and `(1 - delta) * x` will keep with `x.dtype`, being entirely inside `numpy`; but `x[i] ** alpha` and `(1 - delta) * x[i]` will not be so constrained. If you change your code to this, you can verify you are getting the same result:

```
x[i]**np.float32(alpha) + np.float32(1 - delta) * x[i] + y[j] - x[a] - y[b]
```

---

That said, this speed-up is only possible because `x` and `y` are `numpy` arrays: the fact that `numpy` has very efficient storage for numbers, that it does not need to allocate or deallocate things during calculation itself, and the fact that all this is done at a very low level, outside Pythonland. Given that you did not specify [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) in your tags, this may be cheating a little; but you do use `numpy` in your code so I figure it should be fine. If you are fine with a `numpy` answer, adding [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) tag would be good.

In pure Python, the best you can do is pre-calculate what you can:

```
xi = [vx**alpha + (1 - delta) * vx for vx in x]
```

then run your loop, replacing `x[i]**alpha + (1 - delta) * x[i]` with `xi[i]`. There is nothing more that can be done to make this faster.

Comment: Thanks, Amadan, you are my lifesaver. After the problem is replaced with a 4 demensional array calculation, I also have a related question if I may ask. Let's say I want to find the `np.argmax` in matrix `z` in every `T by T` area such that 
```for i,j in product(range(T),range(T)):  
np.argmax(z[i*T:(i+1)*T,j*T:(j+1)*T])```. 

Is there any way to optimize this kind of loop too?

Comment: There is, but I'm not _that_ great at dimensioning and it's late :P But in short, use `moveaxis` or `transpose` to get the `z4` above into `i, j, a, b` order of axes (or construct it in that order); then `reshape` to `[T*T, T*T]` to get two axes `i*T+j, a*T+b`.  The first axis lists `T*T` slices, each of which has `T*T` elements in the second axis. You can just run `argmax` on that, with the `axis` parameter; this gets you one argmax for each slice, in a `[T*T]` vector, where the axis is `[i*T+j]`. Then use `reshape` to get `[T, T]` matrix, with two axes, for `i, j` respectively. More or less.

Comment: Oh wait, you just renamed `a` into `j` in this second part. No need to reshape at start, `z4` should be fine as is. I think. Axes make my head hurt. :P But I hope you got the gist of the solution. Separate the dimensions into "linear index of slices" and "linear index of element in a slice", run `argmax` over the correct axis, run `reshape` to separate the linear argmax result into 2D.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `product(range(T),range(T),range(T),range(T))` is `50^4` times of iteration in python, in which for loop is extremely slow.

---

- Optimize

Cache the same value to avoid repeat caculations in for loop. 
for example:

- `(1 - delta)` is repeated `50^4` times
- `x[i]**alpha` is repeated `50^3` times
- ...

So code like this:

```py
_delta = 1 - delta
# other caches
for i,j,a,b in product(range(T), repeat=4):
    z[i*T+a,j*T+b]    =  x[i]**alpha + _delta * x[i] + y[j] - x[a] - y[b]
```

Comment: Mathematically, there can be no reassignments to elements of `z`, unless some were assigned before the loop; each value of `(i*T+a,j*T+b)` is unique. Also, even if they were not, I can't understand why you would skip the calculation if it was `np.nan` — seems an odd condition to test for here.

Comment: I have fixed part of reassignments, thank you for correction!